# How to capture or prevent "The application failed to initialize properly (0x########). Click OK to terminate the application."

Tags: winapi, createprocess

I have a .net console application that I wrote that is being run in the background with CreateProcess. When we run it from a machine without .net installed it pops a window saying 
"The application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000135). Click OK to terminate the application."

I need this application to return an error when it can't start rather than popping up an interactive message box. Is there any way to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: Either make the calling application check or make sure that the required runtimes are installed with it. Without the runtimes, it can't do much else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before calling`CreateProcess`, call `SetThreadErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)`.

Comment: Well, best of all is to call `SetErrorMode(SEM_FAILCRITICALERRORS)` at process startup.

Comment: I actually used SetErrorMode but it worked like a charm guys. Thanks.